# Laravel 5 dynamic url

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hello i am Working on application using laravel 5 framework

i am facing issue with the url() function, Basically i have a database which consists of product_id column. `url('/product/2)` i would like to replace the numeric value and make it fetch from the database i:e replace 2 with the current **product_id**

the below code is where i would like to fetch the data from database

```
<a href="{!! url('/productBasedFAQ/2') !!}" class="list-group-item">{!! $product->product_name !!}</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `$product->product_id` to get the id

```
<a href="{!! url('productBasedFAQ/'.$product->product_id) !!}" class="list-group-item">{!! $product->product_name !!}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel `HTML::link` Helper. More about link helper [click here](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/186/generating-a-html-link).